# How to convert using GPG armor to ASCII using Bouncycastle without encryption?

Tags: java, ascii, gnupg, pgp, converters

I need to convert data to ASCII in Java with parameters

```
gpg --armor --no-verbose --no-greeting --no-secmem-warning --no-permission-warning -z 6 -o 2 --store 1
```

how to convert with same parameters using bouncy castle?
I've found hundreds of examples, but all with encryption.

I want to achieve only same format of data, which is expected with external system - result of

```
gpg --armor --no-verbose --no-greeting --no-secmem-warning --no-permission-warning -z 6 -o 2 --store 1.
```

Text file with 'test' in the body looks like this after conversion

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

owFbw53EaBgTkPetJLW4BAA=
=SL6Q
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of both the formatted and unformatted data?

Comment: Question updated, thx!